# jQuery: .gif animation is not working

Tags: jquery, animation, gif, progress

In my project I want to display .gif animation (need to display the rotating wheel, to indicate the data is getting downloaded) till the data gets from Server, after clicking the “Display Product Details”.

For this I followed two approaches:

1st approach is using Ajax (in 1st approach data is appending to the page after getting response), and the 2nd approach is without Ajax (the page get refreshed).

As per the requirement I need to implement the functionality in 2nd approach.  But in the 2nd approach the animation is not working (the wheel is not rotating). It seems browser is busy with waiting for the response. Here below I am giving the jQuery code for the two approaches. Could anybody suggest how to make it work with 2nd approach. Thanks in advance.

1st approach:

```
function DisplayProductDetails () {
    $(‘ a#getProdutDetails).click(function (e) {         
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (response) {
            $("div.loadingIndicator").show();
            if (response.length > 0) {
                $('body').append(response);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
}
```

2nd approach:

```
function DisplayProductDetails () {
    $(‘ a#getProdutDetails').click(function (e) {     
        $("div.loadingIndicator").show();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        window.document.location = link;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this `$(‘ a#getProdutDetails')` should be `$('#getProdutDetails a')`

Comment: when do you call `DisplayProductDetails()`?

Comment: I don't understand what the point of the second approach is. You are reinventing a simple anchor tag with JS. All you do is redirect to the value of the href in anchor tag. That's what it does naturally already. And the loading indicator will never show, because the redirect will happen right away. No time for the image to show up.

Comment: @ROYFinley "getProdutDetails" is the id of anchor tag.

Comment: @t.niese in document ready method of page.

Comment: @Venkat, to clarify: when the link is clicked a loading animation is displayed until the page is ready and then you want to change the browser location to the page that was called?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why you want to do this and this is the best thing I could come up with:

```
<div>
    <a href='http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/' id='theLink'>Click here to redirect</a>
    <img style='display:none;' id='Loading' alt='Loading...' src='http://oilandgas.rockwellautomation.com/images/loading.gif'>
</div>


$(function(){
    $('#theLink').click(function(e){
        $(document).queue('LoadPage',function(next){
            $('#Loading').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                setTimeout(function(){next();},1000);
            });
        });

        $(document).queue('LoadPage',function(next){
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            window.document.location = link;        
        });

        $(document).dequeue('LoadPage');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

What it does is force the loading image to be shown before the link is followed. If your browser does not clear the page as soon as it starts to navigate, then the user will see the loading gif while the browser fetches the linked resource.

from my own observations it seems most browsers won't clear the current page until they receive a response back from the resource you are trying to retrieve. In this case the user will see the image until the page is cleared.

[Here is a fiddle of the solution I show above.](http://jsfiddle.net/4wdgm/3/) If you have a slow connection you can probably see what I am talking about, otherwise it will redirect faster than the image can be shown.

By delaying the image show with fade in and then using the queue to separate those actions in code, you have an opportunity to see the image even with a fast connection. If you wanted to ensure the image was seen before the page redirected, you could always add a delay in there like this:

```
 $(document).queue('LoadPage',function(next){
    $('#Loading').fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).show(function(){
        next();
    });
 });
```

[Here is an example of that method](http://jsfiddle.net/uumPd/4/)